# Gradient Descent for Tensor Decomposition - Find low rank dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, gradient-descent, tensor-decomposition

I encountered this [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2623330.2623656) on travel time estimation using Tensor Decomposition and at Page 4, Figure 5 there is an algorithm to decompose a tensor using Gradient Descent.

The first line of this algorithm initializes six low-rank matrices. I don't understand how is it possible to initialize these matrices if their *dimensions* is not known in advance (they are not in the Input section).

In the aforementioned paper, it is not mentioned how the *dimensions* are computed and I am stumbling around in the dark at the moment.

I am trying to understand something from this [tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01668.pdf), but it is quite hard to understand for me and if you could at least point me to something more readable would be awesome.

Thanks to everyone willing to help.

Comment: But the dimensions are given? $\mathcal{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M \times 2 L}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2 L \times P}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times Q}$. The internal dimensions $d_R, d_U, d_T$ are probably hyper-parameters.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment. "Hyper-parameters" seems to be a reasonable hypothesis, I don't know why this is not point out in the paper.